# Merging Jar Files (Or a ZIP with a Jar) in C++

Tags: java, c++, jar, zip, minecraft

I have a jar file and a zip file. I need to move the contents of the .zip into the .jar--how can I do this using C++? I have no pre-existing code, not really sure where to begin. Is there a system() batch command that can merge the files? Perhaps even just the "copy" command with some operator?

I do not want to use 7z or winRAR, I'd like this to be all C++ or maybe even batch if there is a way via system(). I just don't want users to have to download those utilities in order for this launcher to work.

The application of this is with a custom Minecraft launcher. I need to merge the forge files with the Minecraft.jar file. Its illegal to distribute a modded Minecraft.jar--Gotta download the normal one from Minecraft, then the mods, and then combine.

Thanks!

Comment: "I need to accomplish X, how do I do it' questions are just too broad for SO.

Comment: I have googled this thoroughly--can't find any documentation. I do not believe this question is not too broad, I only need a reference to some article or the line of code that might accomplish this.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I tried to edit it into a more understandable question. Is the edit more appropriate? I had no idea where to search--even after reading a dozen or so resources on Google I could not find any C++ methods to accomplish what I was asking.

Comment: This is not a question for this website.

Comment: @GalenNare Could you please explain why? How can I fix it? Instead of just insulting my question, could you be constructive?

Comment: Your question was so broad that it could have been assumed you mean something like WinRAR or 7Zip until you edited the question. Plus this question might be better helped in the Arquade community.

Comment: @GalenNare Thanks, I'll keep that in mind in the future and edit this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest answer to this question is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918234/batch-deleting-files-while-performing-a-copy-merge). It explains how to accomplish this using batch, which can be implemented into C++.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like 7zip- Unzip both to the same directory, then rezip as a .jar as they are essentially the same.

```
7z e 1.8.3.jar
7z e mod.zip
del 1.8.3.jar
del mod.zip
7z a 1.8.3.jar
```

probably a way better way to do this, but 7zip is easy to work with.

Comment: Thanks, but what if the user does not have 7 zip installed? Perhaps there is a way via command prompt? I've seen zip's be merged with jpegs before, not sure if that would work here?

Comment: @SeargentGen you include 7z with the launcher.