# Batch Deleting Files While Performing a Copy/Merge

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, copy

I have 2 files, "launcher.jar" and "camStudio.jar" that I need merged. I decided to try to do this using batch with the code:

```
copy /b launcher.jar + camStudio.jar file.jar
```

However, the resulting "file.jar" only contains the contents of "camStudio.jar". How can I prevent the files in "launcher.jar" from being deleted?

Comment: What does this have to do with java?

Comment: @BrettOkken The jar files contain java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining the contents of two `.jar` files is a little more complicated than just calling `copy` from the command line. Rather than a normal directory, `.jar` files are a type of compressed file, so you need special utilities to manipulate them. Fortunately these tools come with the standard JKD.

The JDK comes with the utility `jar` that is unsurprisingly used for manipulating `.jar` files. It's usage is described as this:

```
Usage: jar {ctxui}[vfmn0Me] [jar-file] [manifest-file] [entry-point] [-C dir] files ...
Options:
    -c  create new archive
    -t  list table of contents for archive
    -x  extract named (or all) files from archive
    -u  update existing archive
    -v  generate verbose output on standard output
    -f  specify archive file name
    -m  include manifest information from specified manifest file
    -n  perform Pack200 normalization after creating a new archive
    -e  specify application entry point for stand-alone application
        bundled into an executable jar file
    -0  store only; use no ZIP compression
    -M  do not create a manifest file for the entries
    -i  generate index information for the specified jar files
    -C  change to the specified directory and include the following file
If any file is a directory then it is processed recursively.
The manifest file name, the archive file name and the entry point name are
specified in the same order as the 'm', 'f' and 'e' flags.

Example 1: to archive two class files into an archive called classes.jar:
       jar cvf classes.jar Foo.class Bar.class
Example 2: use an existing manifest file 'mymanifest' and archive all the
           files in the foo/ directory into 'classes.jar':
       jar cvfm classes.jar mymanifest -C foo/ .
```

Relevant commands for combining two `.jar` files are `x` and `c`. Even with this, combining the `.jar` files takes more than a line or two, so I put together this `.bat` files to automate it.

```
:: Pass one or more .jar files as command line arguments
:: Combine_Jar [file1] [file2 ...]
:: Combine_Jar Test.jar
:: Combine_Jar Test.jar Test2.jar Test3.jar
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "jarDir=%cd%"
set "newJar="
set "folders="
pushd %temp%
for %%a in (%*) do (
    call :extract %%a
    set "newJar=!newJar!_%%~na_"
)



set "tempDirs=!newJar:_=^"!"
set "tempDirs=%tempDirs:^"^"=^" ^"%"

set "newJar=!newJar:~1,-1!.jar"
set "newJar=!newJar:__=_!"
if exist "!newJar!" del /Q "!newJar!"

jar cf "!newJar!" %tempDirs%

for %%a in (%*) do call rd /s /q  "%%~na"

move /Y "!newJar!" "%jarDir%" > nul
popd
exit /B

:extract
set "tempDir=%~n1"

if exist "%tempDir%" (
    rd /s /q "%tempDir%"
)
md "%tempDir%"

pushd "%tempDir%"
jar xf "%jarDir%\%~1"
popd
exit /B
```

It will all jar files passed as arguments into a single jar files.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks so much, incredibly helpful to myself and probably many others. Thank you for taking the time to type that together!

Comment: @SeargentGen I improved the batch  code so that it can combine an arbitrary number of batch files.